# The meaning of [$@var-name] use in mysql ExtractValue() function

Tags: mysql

```
@xml= '<a><b>X</b><b>Y</b></a>'; 
set @i=1,@j=2;
select extractvalue(@xml,'//b[$@i]');
```

I would like to know the meaning of `$@` use in the function.

Answer (score 1):

`$@` stands for user variable. See [MySQL Documentation: User variables (weak checking)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)

First of all in your posted code `@xml= 'XY';` is not a valid XML.

To explain, `//b[$@i]` is a `XPATH` query. In that `$@i` is does kind of variable interpolation. An example from the documentation,

```
SET @xml = '<a><b>X</b><b>Y</b></a>';
SET @i =1;
```

Then doing `SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '//b[$@i]');` returns `X` sine it essentially says

select the first ([1] index) tag element `b`. So here, `'//b[$@i]'` is nothing but saying `'//b[1]'`